# Snowflake - Get a list of dates between a Start and End Date for a record

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, recursive-query, date-arithmetic

I need to repeat a record for each day between a start and end date
Fields are:
`ID`, `Name`, `Start_date`, `End_date`

Values are:

```
001, Record1, 2023-04-01 00:00:00.000, 2023-06-30 00:00:00.000
```

I'm trying to get this:
`001, Record1, [Every single day between these dates]`

```
- 001, Record1, 2023-04-01 
- 001, Record1, 2023-04-02 
- 001, Record1, 2023-04-03
- --- so on and so on 
- 001, Record1, 2023-06-29 
- 001, Record1, 2023-06-30
```

Comment: I got stuck on the recursive CTE part, just rusty as it's been some time since I've had to create one from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

That's a typical use case for [a recursive CTE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/queries-cte#recursive-ctes-and-hierarchical-data). In Snowflake:

```
with recursive rcte as (
    select id, name, start_date, end_date from mytable
    union all
    select id, name, start_date + interval '1 day', end_date from rcte where start_date < end_date
)
select * from id, name, start_date from rcte
```